# Windows 8.1 installation: Which drive is the F drive?

Tags: windows-8, usb, external-hard-drive, windows-8.1, windows-installation

I am doing a clean install of Windows 8.1 on an old PC. It was purchased as download from Microsoft Store and written to and booted from a USB flash drive.

It went through all of these steps:

1. Copying Windows Files
2. Getting files ready for installation
3. Installing features
4. Installing updates

Then at "Getting finished" I am stuck at this stupid dialog box.

> Please unplug the following external drive and click OK to restart
>   your computer and finish installing Windows.
>
> F:

How do I tell what physical drive this is? Can I drop to command prompt during installation? And is it safe to unplug it while powered on?

There is no external hard drive connected, none that I can see. There is no USB or FireWire drive connected externally. I think it sees one of the internal drives as external... in some weird way?!

Comment: Press Shift+F10 to bring up a command prompt, type the following command, and post here the output: `wmic logicaldisk get caption,filesystem,size,volumename`

Comment: @and31415 Thanks! It's getting devices ready now. The problem was the USB flash drive that I used to boot and install the system from. The main problem was figuring out which one is the F drive. You can post your comment as an answer, I can update it with the output from the wmic command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to bring up a command prompt.
2. Type the following command:

   ```
   wmic logicaldisk get caption,filesystem,size,volumename
   ```

### Example output

```
Caption  FileSystem  Size          VolumeName       
C:       NTFS        366997504     System Reserved  
D:       NTFS        20974428160   System           
E:       FAT32       80004153344   80 GB            
F:       FAT32       7721713664    ESD-USB          
G:       NTFS        53884649472   Datadisk N
H:       NTFS        315183595520  Backup           
I:       NTFS        59073925120   Datadisk         
J:       NTFS        130668294144                   
K:                                                  
L:                                                  
X:       NTFS        533640192     Boot
```

### Further reading

- [Description of the Windows Setup Function Keys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295116/en-us)
- [Win32_LogicalDisk class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Comment: It was that "ESD-USB" device that was the problem. That's the bootable USB flash drive I created to install Windows. I just removed it and was then able to reboot and complete the installation. The Shift+F10 shortcut was the solution. I knew about the wmic command, I actually learned about that a few days ago when I needed it. But I had forgotten about the shortcut to drop to command prompt. Thanks again!

Comment: @sammyg You're welcome. The output leaves me wondering what are those `K:` and `L:` letters associated with.

Comment: Answering myself: those letters should be associated with empty optical disk drives (ODDs).