# Windows 8.1 Installation: device removal and restart

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, usb

I'm doing a windows 8.1 clean installation.  It was purchased as download from the Microsoft Store and written to and booted from a USB flash drive.

The installation creates hard drive partitions, preps and installs the files, etc.  Then in the "finishing up" section, a dialogue box pops up which tells me to remove the USB drive I am booting the installation from:

> Please unplug the following external drive and click OK to restart
>   your computer and finish installing Windows.
>
> F:

My only choice at that point is to follow the instructions.  But when the system restarts, it tells me there is nothing to boot from, and I am forced to start the installation process over from scratch.

There are no other storage devices connected to the computer than the USB I am booting from.

I followed the steps from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/759641/windows-8-1-installation-which-drive-is-the-f-drive) to try and fix the problem.  The offending drive is indeed the USB stick I'm installing from.  One thing I noticed in the contents however was that the reported size of the drive was a few digits greater than any other, which doesn't make sense.  Perhaps there's just a decimal error but maybe a clue as well.

Hoping to get this fixed soon.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to change boot order in BIOS/UEFI so it looks for the HDD first?

Answer (score 0):

When the installation prompts you to remove your drive, and restart, do not remove the drive! Perform a restart, and if prompted, tell the system to boot from the hard drive.

Comment: This loads to a "No bootable devices, press any key to reset"